# Calling MouseListener for two different things

Tags: java, shapes, mouselistener

public class Application extends JFrame {
public Rectangle.MyMouseHandler handler;

```
public class MyMouseHandler extends MouseAdapter{
    
    public void MouseClicked(MouseEvent e){
        if (e.getModifiers() == MouseEvent.BUTTON3_MASK && e.getClickCount() == 1) {
        initUI1();
    }
     if (e.getModifiers() == MouseEvent.BUTTON1_MASK && e.getClickCount() == 1){
         initUI2();
     }       
}
}
                 

private void initUI1() {

    add(new Rectangle());

    setSize(800, 800);

    setTitle("Application");
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
}    
private void initUI2() {

    add(new Circle());

    setSize(800, 800);

    setTitle("Application");
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
}
/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
     EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {
        Application ex = new Application();
        ex.setVisible(true);
    });
}
}
```

I want to make a program in which I can draw a rectangle and a circle with my left click of the mouse and use right click to switch between the two. I have already made both the Circle and Rectangle classes.

Answer (score 1):

A trivial solution is to introduce a `boolean` **member** variable that serves as a switch between the two possible states, *i.e.*

- ready to draw a circle
- ready to draw a rectangle

This could look as follows:

```
// if true then the next shape to be drawn should be a circle
private boolean drawCircleNext = true;
```

So looking at your mouse listener, you need to switch on right-click and check status before drawing on left-click:

```
public void MouseClicked( MouseEvent e )
{
    // assuming BUTTON3_MASK equals a right-click
    if( e.getModifiers() == MouseEvent.BUTTON3_MASK && e.getClickCount() == 1 ) 
    {
        drawCircleNext = !drawCircleNext;
    }
    
    // assuming BUTTON1_MASK equals a left-click
    if( e.getModifiers() == MouseEvent.BUTTON1_MASK && e.getClickCount() == 1 )
    {
        if( drawCircleNext ) 
        {
            initUI2();
        }
        else
        {
            initUI1();
        }
    }    
}
```

This simple version should suffice already to get started.

Comment: And how do i call the MouseClicked method in my main class. Because the first class is the Application class and the other class is MyMouseHandler.

Answer (score 0):

I would use an `enum` to save the actual drawing mode (easily expandable):

```
    private enum Mode {
        RECTANGLE, CIRCLE;
    }

    private Mode mode = Mode.RECTANGLE;
```

The code for switching the mode, called from the listener (right click), changes the mode according the actual mode:

```
    private void changeMode(MouseEvent ignored) {
        mode = switch (mode) {
            case CIRCLE -> Mode.RECTANGLE;
            case RECTANGLE -> Mode.CIRCLE;
            default -> throw new IllegalArgumentException(mode + " not implemented");
        };
    }
```

and the code from adding a shape (left click), will check the mode and add the corresponding shape:

```
    private void addShape(MouseEvent ev) {
        var x = ev.getX()-SIZE/2;
        var y = ev.getY()-SIZE/2;
        var shape = switch (mode) {
            case CIRCLE -> new Ellipse2D.Double(x, y, SIZE, SIZE);
            case RECTANGLE -> new Rectangle(x, y, SIZE, SIZE);
            default -> throw new IllegalArgumentException(mode + " not implemented");
        };
        shapes.add(shape);
        repaint();
    }
```

`shapes` is just a `List<Shape>` containing the shapes to be drawn (inside a class extending `JComponent` or `JPanel`).

```
    private final List<Shape> shapes = new ArrayList<>();
    ...
    
    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        shapes.forEach(((Graphics2D)g)::draw);
    }
```

finally, the mouse listener (`MouseAdapter`) would call:

```
    private void doMouseClicked(MouseEvent ev) {
        switch (ev.getButton()) {
            case MouseEvent.BUTTON1:
                addShape(ev);
                break;
            case MouseEvent.BUTTON3:
                changeMode(ev);
                break;
            default:
                // empty
                break;
        }
    }
```